# Resource function - magento

Tags: magento

I am trying to create new extension in magento. I have created custom table for our extension. I want to select values from our custom table. For this I have tried following.

In our Company_name/Module_name/Model/file.php, I have used following code for calling Resource function.

```
return Mage::getResourceModel('Modulename/filename')->functionName();
```

It works fine on our project

But If I use following snippet,

```
return $this->_getResource()->functionname();
```

It returns following error

```
a:5:{i:0;s:20:"Resource is not set.";i:1;s:3048:"#0 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(136): Mage::throwException('Resource is not...')
```

And also I have configured our resource class by adding following code to module/etc/config.xml

```
<models>
    <modulename>
        <class>Companyname_Modulename_Model_Filename</class>
        <resourceModel>modulename_resource</resourceModel>
    </modulename>
    <modulename_resource>
        <class>Companyname_Modulename_Model_Resource</class>
    </modulename_resource>
</models>
```

I don't know where I made mistake. If you know Let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

See the resource model definition

```
<?php
protected function _getResource()
{
    if (empty($this->_resourceName)) {
        Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('core')->__('Resource is not set.'));
    }

    return Mage::getResourceSingleton($this->_resourceName);
}
```

So it throws exception when `$_resourceName` of class `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` is not set or empty. So before calling `_getResource()` method, just set that variable. That is

```
  $this->_resourceName = 'modulename/filename';
  $this->_getResource()->functionname();
```

You can also use this.

```
  $this->_setResourceModel('modulename/filename');
  return $this->_getResource()->functionname();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: In magento core module like catalog, newsletter I have 't seen $this->_getResource.. that is why I am asked.

Comment: this method is defined in `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php`. Whether my answer helped you ?